# Interpreting #define PRINTF if(false) printf in C++

Tags: c++, macros

I am analyzing the following macro in C++:

```
#define PRINTF if(false) printf
```

Does this mean, instead of typing `printf(" .... ");` one can just use `PRINTF("...")`?  Or is `PRINTF` activated only if a boolean in the code is true?

Comment: This is not a good macro; consider `if ( test ) PRINTF("success"); else PRINTF("fail");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be made to toggle output on and off. As it currently stands,

```
PRINTF("What ever");
```

will never print anything as it expands to

```
if(false) printf("What ever");
```

You can then toggle output on by changing

```
#define PRINTF if(false) printf
```

to

```
#define PRINTF if(true) printf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define PRINTF if(false) printf
```

is a macro for `PRINTF`, which will replace the latter with

```
if(false) printf
```

in your code. So whenever you write

```
PRINTF("something")
```

it is translated to

```
if(false) printf("something")
```

i.e., it is not executed. It is probably useful for debugging, when you may want your `PRINTF` "cancelled". To keep it displaying stuff, you'll just change the macro to

```
#define PRINTF if(true) printf
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you write

> PRINTF("this does nothing" );

it would textually replace it by

```
if(false) printf("this does nothing" );
```

So basically it would do nothing as the condition is always false.

Answer (score 0):

As others already told you, this is a way to switch output on and off.

However, it's a particulary **error-prone** way of doing so.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINTF if(false) printf

int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    int i = 0;

    if (x) {
        PRINTF("What ever");
    else
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Can you guess what `i` will be?

The answer is it will be `1`, because the compiler does not care about accidental wrong indentation, and the `PRINTF` macro expands as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINTF if(false) printf

int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    int i = 0;

    if (x) {
        if(false) printf("What ever");
    else
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Which is more easily read as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINTF if(false) printf

int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    int i = 0;

    if (x) {
        if(false)
            printf("What ever");
        else
            i = 1;
    }
}
```

[**Macros are evil!**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-vs-macros)

You should use a different way of toggling output anyway. In fact, you should not blindly turn off logging messages in "release" versions (which seems to be this macro's intent), because this is where you will later need them most. On the other hand, only the most basic toy applications should unconditionally use direct standard output with `printf` or `std::cout`. You should instead operate on `std::ostream` references. Search for related Stack Overflow questions about logging in C++. The topic is quite complex.